# Mysql, select value of one cell depending on contents of another cell

Tags: mysql

My current code

```
SELECT post_id, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) - RADIANS( -117.55 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM wp_postmeta WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%location_l%' HAVING distance < 2500 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Here are two sample row of data (meta_key is not always long or lat):

```
post_id = 123  
meta_key = location_longitude  
meta_value = -119.890000  

post_id = 123  
meta_key = location_latitude   
meta_value = 42.170000
```

How do I modify my query to replace 'lat' and 'lng' in my original query to be the contents of the meta_value listed above? Something like this?

```
select meta_value where meta_key = location_latitude
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `GROUP BY post_id`, you should be able to use `MAX()` aggregates in place of `lat,lng`, surrounding `CASE` statements which determine whether the current row is latitude or longitude.  The others will be NULL, and therefore eliminated by the aggregate.

I think this ought to work so you won't need any subselects.

```
SELECT
   post_id, 
   ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='location_latitude' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) ) ) * COS( RADIANS( MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='location_longitude' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) ) - RADIANS( -117.55 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='location_latitude' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE `meta_key` IN ('location_latitude','location_longitude')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING distance < 2500 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

The moving parts here are:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='location_latitude' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END)
```

This translates as:  If this row's `meta_key` is `'location_latitude'`, return the `meta_value`, otherwise return NULL.  We expect then that since two rows are returned for the `post_id` (lat,lng), the `MAX()` value returned above is always the non-null one -- the correct latitude or longitude value from `meta_value`.

Comment: This worked great! You missed one lat near the end of my original code, but I swapped that out and it worked great.

Comment: @user1286782 Sorry - didn't scroll far enough rightwards.  I edited it above for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to replace the reference to the table (i.e. `FROM wp_postmeta`) in your query with an inline view, something like this:

```
FROM
( SELECT plat.post_id
       , plat.meta_value AS lat
       , plng.meta_value AS lng
    FROM wp_postmeta plat
    JOIN wp_postmeta plng
      ON plat.post_id = plng.post_id
         AND plat.meta_key = 'location_latitude'
         AND plng.meta_ley = 'location_longitude'
) wpm
```

(NOTE: this assumes that there is only one row for each post_id for each of the two meta_key values of interest...)

This uses an "inline view" to combine the latitude and longitude values for each post_id into a single row.  (You can run just the query for the inline view to confirm that its returning the results you expect.) We can use an inline view in place of a table reference, in more recent versions of MySQL (version >= 5.0).

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table to itself (this is common in databases with EAV structure):

```
SELECT
    post_id,
    distance
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        lng.post_id, 
        ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) 
                     * COS( RADIANS( lat.meta_value ) ) 
                     * COS( RADIANS( lng.meta_value ) 
                          - RADIANS( -117.55 ) ) 
                     + SIN( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) 
                     * SIN( RADIANS( lat.meta_value ) ) 
                     ) 
        ) AS distance 
    FROM wp_postmeta AS lng
      JOIN wp_postmeta AS lat
        ON lat.post_id = lng.post_id
    WHERE lng.meta_key = 'location_longitude'
      AND lat.meta_key = 'location_latitude'
  ) AS tmp
WHERE distance < 2500 
ORDER BY distance 
  LIMIT 0 , 20 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.post_id, 
  ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat.meta_value  ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng.meta_value  ) - RADIANS( -117.55 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 34.09 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat.meta_value  ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM wp_postmeta lat, wp_postmeta lng
WHERE lat.post_id = lng.postID
AND lat.meta_key = 'location_latitude'
AND lng.meta_key = 'location_longitude'
HAVING distance < 2500 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```